# angular 5 behaviorsubject not working with http

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, behaviorsubject

I am trying to get user type from the server and based on the role of the user display data. The http servise is running file and returning the desired data. I have two components. Login and Home components. After login a boolean variable is set to decide if the user is Admin or User. The login function is showing isAdmin variable true. But home component is showing it as false. I am using behaviorsubject and observable to sync the data.

## Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {IPosts} from "./posts";
import {IUser} from "./user";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class ExamService {

  public isAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  cast = this.isAdmin.asObservable();


  private _postsURL = "http://localhost:3292/examservice.svc/ExamQs";
  private _userURL = "http://localhost:3292/examservice.svc/GetUser";

 constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<IPosts[]> {
      return this.http
          .get(this._postsURL)
          .map((response: Response) => {
                 return <IPosts[]>response.json();
         })
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getUser(user:string,pass:string): Observable<IUser[]> {
      return this.http
          .get(this._userURL+"/"+user+"/"+pass)
          .map((response: Response) => {
              return <IUser[]>response.json();
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  checkAdmin(data){
    this.isAdmin.next(data);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
      return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
}
```

## Login Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ExamService } from "../exam.service";
import {IPosts} from "../posts";
import {IUser} from "../user"; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [ ExamService ]
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  _postsArray: IPosts[];
  _userArray: IUser[];
  ifuser: boolean = false;
  Name: string;
  Pass: string;
  validated: boolean = true;


  constructor(private apiSerivce: ExamService,private router:Router) { }

  getPosts(): void {

        this.apiSerivce.getUser(this.Name,this.Pass)
            .subscribe(
            resultArray => {
              this._userArray = resultArray;

              if(this._userArray[0].Role == "Admin")
              {
                this.ifuser = true;
                this.apiSerivce.checkAdmin(this.ifuser); 
              }
              else
              {
                this.apiSerivce.checkAdmin(this.ifuser);
                this.router.navigate(['']);
              }

            },
              error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
            )
            console.log(this.ifuser);
            this.router.navigate(['']);


    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

      this.apiSerivce.cast.subscribe(data => 
    {
          this.validated = data;
          console.log("Login " + this.validated);
        });


    }
  }
```

## Home Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExamService } from "../exam.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [ ExamService ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  validated: boolean;
  constructor(private apiSerivce: ExamService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiSerivce.cast.subscribe(data => 
      {
        this.validated = data;
        console.log("Home " + this.validated);
      });


  }

}
```

Comment: @acdcjunior thank you but this is another way of writing the same code. It is not working. The problem is in home component. The value is not changing in home component.

Comment: You are having multiple `console.log` can you show in `comment` where are you getting which value? Coz I don't think both console.log in login would be giving true. Also copy your code to `stackblitz` project, would be easier to see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem. Do not add service as provider in the child components instead add provider in app.component.ts file which is a parent component. so instead of

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [ ExamService ]
})
```

it should be like this in child components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
```

and in app.component.ts file it should be like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ ExamService ]
})
```